# Ubuntu and Chromebook

Tags: chromebook

I am pretty new to this. I got a Lenovo Gaming 16” and basically put it into full ROM, couldn’t boot it into windows 11. So I’m trying out Ubuntu, except. Every time after restarting I’m taken back to the developer mode starting screen where it gives me boot options. That’s where I’d have to use an alternate bootloader ‘edk2’ to boot into Ubuntu. I was wondering if or how I could get it to just boot into Ubuntu on start-up or is that not possible?

Comment: I am Infact live usb booting.

Comment: Did you install the full UEFI ROMfrom MrChromeBox?